# Total probability of Conditional Probability

Tags: probability

Suppose that we have a conditional probability $P(x | y)$ and a partition $x'$ of the sample space. How can we apply the law of total probability to conclude that
$$P(x|y) = \sum\limits_{x'}^{} P((x|y)\cap x')?$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is rather straightforward, use the fact that for any events $A$ and $B$
$$P( A \cap B )= P(B)P(A|B).$$

Thus $P((x|y) \cap x^{\prime}) = P((x|y)|x^{\prime})P(x^{\prime})$, so by the law of total probability

$$P(x|y) = \sum_{x^{\prime} }P((x|y)|x^{\prime})P(x^{\prime})=\sum_{x^{\prime} } P((x|y) \cap x^{\prime}).$$

Caution: Using $x^{\prime}$ as the elements from the partition is not the best notation, $\prime$ is often used to denote the complement of an event.

Comment: $P((x|y)|x') = P(x| y, x')$, by the way, is this true ?

Comment: $P(x|y, x^{\prime}) = \frac{P(x \cap y|x^{\prime} )}{P(y | x^{\prime} )}$

Comment: So is there any alternative or equivalent  representation of $P((x|y)|x')$ ?

Comment: It depends what would you like to get; you could apply Bayes' theorem and obtain $$ P( (x|y)|x^{\prime}) = \frac{P(x^{\prime}|(x|y))P(x|y)}{P(x^{\prime})}.$$ If you happy with my answer you can accept it. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, I think this answer also provides a good view of what happens here.

[Proof of Total Probability Theorem for Conditional Probability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2866431/proof-of-total-probability-theorem-for-conditional-probability)

I find it rather confusing to use condition with 
$$\sum_{z}P((x|y)|z)P(z) \\\text{z here in place of x' in question}$$
for the event space, $\Omega$ for $Z$ here is not so clear. The space for $Z$, or the value of $P(Z)$ here should be defined over $\Omega_y \cap \Omega_Z$.

This makes the overall answer be either:
$$P(x|y) = \sum^{\Omega_y\cap \Omega_Z}_zP(x|y\cap z)P(z) = \sum_zP(x\cap z|y)$$

Also, as mentioned by Graham Kemp in the comment:

> ∣ is not a set operation; it is the divider between the event being measured and the condition under which the measured. There can only be at most one such divider in a probability measure function.