# Proof of Total Probability Theorem for Conditional Probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory

The law of total probability states:

> Let $\left({\Omega, \Sigma, \Pr}\right)$ be a probability space.
>
> Let $\left\{{B_1, B_2, \ldots}\right\}$ be a partition of $\Omega$ such that $\forall i: \Pr \left({B_i}\right) > 0$.
>
> Then:
> $\displaystyle \forall A \in \Sigma: \Pr \left({A}\right) = \sum_i \Pr \left({A \mid B_i}\right) \Pr \left({B_i}\right)$

I want to prove that this is true also for conditional probabilities. So basically I want to prove the following:

> Let $\left({\Omega, \Sigma, \Pr}\right)$ be a probability space.
>
> Let $\left\{{B_1, B_2, \ldots}\right\}$ be a partition of $\Omega$ such that $\forall i: \Pr \left({B_i}\right) > 0$.
>
> Then:
> $\displaystyle \forall A, C \in \Sigma: \Pr \left({A \mid C}\right) = \sum_i \Pr \left({A \mid C \cap B_i}\right) \Pr \left({B_i}\right)$

---

This is how I attempted it:
$$Pr(A\mid C) = Pr(A|C\cap \Omega) = Pr(A\mid C\cap\left(\bigcup_iB_i\right))$$ because it is a partition. Then, using the fact that [intersection distributes over union](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Intersection_Distributes_over_Union) I got: $$Pr(A\mid C\cap\left(\bigcup_iB_i\right)) = Pr(A \mid \bigcup_i\left(C\cap B_i\right))$$

I can't go any further. I know that in a probability space we have that the probability measure $Pr$ is countably additive. I know that if we have a probability space $(\Omega, \Sigma, \Pr)$ then the triplet $(\Omega, \Sigma, Qr)$ with $$Qr: Qr(A) := Pr(A | C)$$ is a probability space as well. But I have no idea how to use these two information to finish the proof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't state the result for conditional probabilities correctly. Here's an easy way to see how the correct result is derived.

The conditional probability $P_C:=P(\cdot \mid C)$ is a probability measure, so apply the law of total probability to it to get
$$P_C(A) = \sum_i P_C(A \mid B_i)P_C(B_i).$$
Now show that $P_C(A \mid B_i) = P(A \mid B_i \cap C)$. Thus,
$$P(A \mid C) = \sum_i P(A \mid B_i \cap C)P(B_i \mid C).$$
That's the general form of the law of total probability for conditional probabilities. If, in addition, we assume that $B_i$ and $C$ are independent, so that $P(B_i \mid C) = P(B_i)$, then the general law reduces to what you wrote, namely
$$P(A \mid C) = \sum_i P(A \mid B_i \cap C)P(B_i).$$

Comment: According to Wikipedia here (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability#Statement) we have that the latter should be $P(B_i)$

Comment: @Euler_Salter I think you're missing the claim about independence.

Comment: That's it! Now it all makes sense, if it is independent, then your answer looks great!

Comment: I'd rephrase that a bit: if there is independence, then _your_ statement looks great. My answer is general and holds with or without independence assumptions.

Comment: Absolutely correct!

Comment: Is it correct to say that $P_C(A \mid B_i) = P(A | B_i \cap C)$ because $P_C(A \mid B_i) = P((A\mid B_i)\mid C)= \frac{P(A\cap B_i) \mid C)}{P(B_i \mid C)} = \frac{P(A\cap B_i\cap C)}{P(C)} \cdot \frac{P(C)}{P(B_i\cap C)} = \frac{P(A\cap B_i\cap C)}{P(B_i\cap C)} = P(A\mid B_i\cap C)$ ?

Comment: The expression $P((A \mid B_i) \mid C)$ has no meaning, but if you simply delete it, then what you wrote is okay.

Comment: $\mid$ is *not* a set operation; it is the divider between the event being measured and the condition under which the measured. There can only be at most one such divider in a probability measure function.  It would be somewhat more correct to say $$P_C(A\mid B_i)=P_{B_i\cap C}(A)$$...because it is the probability measure of event $A$ under the joint conditions of $B_i$ and $C$